# Limitations on SFAuthenticationSession

Tags: ios, authentication, ios11, sfauthenticationsession

Apple's documentation for the SFAuthenticationSession say it allows sharing a login "along with cookies and website data". My question is whether there is any limitation to the cookies, and what the 'data' entails exactly.

I have seen a case where cookies set in one instance of SFAuthenticationSession do not appear to be present (or available) in another instance. Do only certain cookies get passed this way?

(If anyone knows of any tools to check the exact cookies present in a SFAuthenticationSession instance, please let me know. I tried Web Inspector but it just says "No Inspectable Applications". I am able to get Web Inspector to work with Safari. Note I don't think that Javascript will work since I want to see cookies for all domains.)